# HttpClient reusable instance for simple calls on another methods

Tags: c#, api, http, rest

I wrote a `HttpClient` instantiable class that will be used as reference to simplify API calls in other methods inside other classes, so the user could call it in a simple way when using my project as reference. I made both synchronous and asynchronous methods, as it was requested for me to made like this.

The main class to build the client is built in:

```
public class Client : IDisposable
{
    private static HttpClient _client;

    public Client(bool payment)
    {
        var baseUrl = payment ? "https://payment.apiaddress.com/" : "https://api.apiaddress.com/";

        _client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)};
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", Config.GetToken());
    }

    public void Dispose() => _client.Dispose();

    public HttpResponseMessage Request(Methods method, string url, object data)
    {
        switch (method)
        {
            case Methods.GET: return _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            case Methods.POST: return _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data).Result;
            case Methods.PUT: return _client.PutAsJsonAsync(url, data).Result;
            case Methods.DELETE: return _client.DeleteAsync(url).Result;
            default: return _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        }
    }

    public string Get(string url) => 
        Request(Methods.GET, url, null).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    public string Post(string url, object data) => 
        Request(Methods.POST, url, data).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    public string Put(string url, object data) => 
        Request(Methods.PUT, url, data).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    public string Delete(string url) => 
        Request(Methods.PUT, url, null).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RequestAsync(Methods method, string url, object data)
    {
        switch (method)
        {
            case Methods.GET: return await _client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            case Methods.POST: return await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data).ConfigureAwait(false);
            case Methods.PUT: return await _client.PutAsJsonAsync(url, data).ConfigureAwait(false);
            case Methods.DELETE: return await _client.DeleteAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            default: return await _client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url) => 
        RequestAsync(Methods.GET, url, null);

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, object data) => 
        RequestAsync(Methods.POST, url, data);

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsync(string url, object data) => 
        RequestAsync(Methods.PUT, url, data);

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteAsync(string url) => 
        RequestAsync(Methods.DELETE, url, null);
}
```

It's used on other classes like this one, to start a new checkout for custom objects based on specific models, which are made by a third part:

```
public class Payment
{
    private static readonly Client _client = new Client(true);

    public static async Task<string> CreditAsync(object data)
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("Payment", data);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }

    public static string Credit(object data)
    {
        var response = _client.Post("Payment", data);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The `new Client(true)` value is to provide the both expected address for the API, as there will be moments that in production environment it will use the `api.etc` and other that will use the `payment.etc`, also to use the provided relative path inside the method content as well.

So the usage could be simplified just as:

```
public void Credit() //OR: public async Task CreditAsync()
{
    var transaction = new Transaction<Credit>
    {
        PaymentMethod = new PaymentMethod {Code = "1"},
        Application = "Tests",
        Vendor = "Felipe",
        Customer = new Customer
        {
            //Customer data goes here...
        },
        Products = new List<TransactionProduct>
        {
            //Product data goes here...
        }
    };

    var test = Payment.Credit(transaction); //OR: await Payment.CreditAsync(transaction);
    Console.WriteLine(teste);
}
```

It works fine and provide the expected responses, that I'll do a better treatment later as required, but I would really appreciate any different and more experienced views to know if this could be considered a good approach for this need and/or if there are ways to improve it, as the idea is to release it as a NuGet/SDK for the final project.

Answer (score 7):

#### Dispose Strategy

It seems your class doesn't even need to implement `IDisposable`. [Should dispose HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)

---

#### Single Responsibility

I would extract configuration management from the implementation of `Client`.

```
public Client(string baseUrl)
{
    _baseUrl = baseUrl ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseUrl));
    // ..
}
```

Add a factory for generating the client instance. This one uses hardcoded uri's, but you could also read from a config file or database.

```
public static class ClientFactory
{
    public static Client Create(bool payment)
    {
        var baseUrl = payment 
            ? "https://payment.apiaddress.com/" : "https://api.apiaddress.com/";
        return new Client(baseUrl);
    }
}
```

---

#### Method Design

I have my doubts about having `*..1..*` (junction) method interactions. I would refactor this to `1..1` (simple) or `1..*..1` (fork).

Original `*..1..*`:

> ```
>  public HttpResponseMessage Request(Methods method, string url, object data)
>     {
>         switch (method)
>         {
>             case Methods.GET: return _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
>             case Methods.POST: return _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data).Result;
>             case Methods.PUT: return _client.PutAsJsonAsync(url, data).Result;
>             case Methods.DELETE: return _client.DeleteAsync(url).Result;
>             default: return _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public string Get(string url) => 
>         Request(Methods.GET, url, null).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
>
>     // others ..
> ```

Refactored to `1..1`:

```
public string Get(string url) => 
    _client.GetAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

public string Post(string url, object data) => 
    _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

public string Put(string url, object data) => 
    _client.PutAsJsonAsync(url, data).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

public string Delete(string url) => 
    _client.DeleteAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

And if you really must have wrapper function `1..*..1`:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Request(Methods method, string url, object data)
    {
        switch (method)
        {
            case Methods.GET: return Get(url);
            case Methods.POST: return Post(url, data);
            case Methods.PUT: return Put(url, data);
            case Methods.DELETE: return Delete(url);
            default: return _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, you should be concerned about this behavior:

> ```
> public class Client : IDisposable {
>   private static HttpClient _client;
>
>   public Client(bool payment)
>   {
>     var baseUrl = payment ? "https://payment.apiaddress.com/" : "https://api.apiaddress.com/";
>
>     _client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)};
>     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
>     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
>     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", Config.GetToken());
>   }
>
>   public Uri BaseAddress => _client?.BaseAddress; // Added by HH
>   ....
> ```

Test case

```
  // 
  Client client1 = new Client(true);
  Console.WriteLine(client1.BaseAddress);
  Console.WriteLine();
  Client client2 = new Client(false);
  Console.WriteLine(client1.BaseAddress);
  Console.WriteLine(client2.BaseAddress);
```

Output:

```
https://payment.apiaddress.com/

https://api.apiaddress.com/
https://api.apiaddress.com/
```

As you see the inner `static HttpClient _client` becomes a new instance when `client2` is called and therefore `client1` also changes base address which may result in unexpected behavior.

So as I see it, you can't use this concept with two different base addresses.

A solution could be to provide what could be called a "Dualton" in a fashion like:

```
public class Client : IDisposable
{
  private HttpClient _client;

  private Client(string baseUrl)
  {
    //var baseUrl = payment ? "https://payment.apiaddress.com/" : "https://api.apiaddress.com/";

    _client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", Config.GetToken());
  }

  static Client paymentClient;
  static Client normalClient;

  public static Client Create(bool payment)
  {
    if (payment)
    {
      paymentClient = paymentClient ?? new Client("https://payment.apiaddress.com/");
      return paymentClient;
    }

    normalClient = normalClient ?? new Client("https://api.apiaddress.com/");
    return normalClient;
  }
```

Someone would probably called that an anti pattern?

A more general solution could be to have a `static Dictionary<string, Client> clients` and the matching `public static Client Create(string baseUrl) {}`.